# String Array Inside Response Listener Gives Null values outside the Listener Class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-volley

I am Fetching data from remote server through JSONObject. Problem is That when i try to save the response string into a string array for its use outside the response listener then the string array gives null values . What should i do so that string  which i get from remote server can be outside the response listener.

Main Activity . java code is below

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  MySingleton singleton;
    TextView textView;
   TextView textView2;

   Button button;
   RequestQueue rqueue;

final String url="http://www.muftiattaullahmultani.com/greeting.php";

public static int count=0;

public final String[] str=new String[2];

public String s;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest= new 
     JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new 
     Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

    while(count<response.length())
    {
        JSONObject object= null;
        try {
            object = response.getJSONObject(count);
            String s = object.getString("id") +"  "+ object.getString("name")+"  " + object.getString("password");
            str[0]=s;
            textView.setText(str[0]);
            count++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
   textView.setText("ERROR");
  }
   });







      MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    textView2.setText(str[0]);

}}
```

TextView 1 gives the correct values but the textview2 gives NuLL values ..

Comment: well in your code you only assign data to textview1 and to first index in array. You don't assign any values to textview2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with
>   data fetched asynchronously from the network.

`Volley` make asynchronous requests, that mean it doesn't block the main thread until the request ends, so the `textView2.setText` will be executed before the `str` array is filled with the data. You need to put it inside the `onResponse`

Comment: so what should i do if i have to send str[] array to the listView,should i declare listview inside the     onResponse     as well i.e     ListView= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,str); inside    onResponse()

Comment: you have 2 choises : first : what you said so you do all the listview work inside the onresponse method. second you do the lisview work outside the onresponse method and you call notifyDataSetChanged() inside the onresponse